# mlockall & shared libs

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am bit confused about the following sentence which appears in the manual of mlockall.

> mlockall() locks all pages mapped into the address space of the calling process. This includes the pages of the code, data and stack segment, as well as shared libraries, user space kernel data, shared memory, and memory-mapped files.

Does this mean that `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE)` will read in advance all the pages of a shared library and lock them into memory when the function is invoked? Or when those pages are actually needed by the process?

Comment: Does mlockall do something special in the case of embedded Linux variants that do not have swap. On all usch distributions that I tried it looks like mlockall maps in the RSS the entire shared library. I believe that this is expected because there is no swap and hdd in which case the entire rootfs is already in the memory. Is my judgment correct?

Answer (score 0):

No. Just when the pages are needed by the process. The only thing `mlockall` does is stop pages from being loaded into swap space (swapped).

Comment: but what about this sequence of steps: first call dlopen("shared lib") and later mlockall. In this case the entire lib should be read in and all the pages mapped into physical memory ... or?!

Comment: No, the memory should be able to be read in as used. It just can't be swapped after that. All `mlockall` does is stop pages from being swapped.